# Copy database from SQL server management to another instance Directely

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

There are many ways to transfer databases from server to another.
Some wizard and other programmatic as SMO
 That have Backup And Restore Classes 
That can help to take backup from server and restore to destination.

If there are way to copy database directly without backup and restore
Programmatic ?

Where I determine the source that need to take copy of database and 
Destination that need to send database to it .
(I know the wizard way of sql  server But i need it programmatic ).

please help .

Answer (score 0):

To do it programmatic way you need to:
1. Somehow get script or information about database structure including DB metadata, DB files, tables, table columns, indexes, etc
2. Create empty DB on destination server
3. Read data from source db and copy to destination db.

This is initial thoughts

Comment: I know this way and i have all thoughts that transfer database from source to destination but i need some thing like dll  to manage this all steps as one atomic way